# Add unix end of line

Tags: unix, end-of-line

Let's say I want to create a line that I would put in a unix file.

if it was windows, in the php program, I would write :

```
 $line .= '\r\n';
```

What would I write for unix to have unix end of line and go to the next line?

How can I make it work for any environment ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In unix you would simply use `$line .= '\n';` as `\n` is the character that defines a new line.

Comment: great... is there a way to make it work under windows and unix ?

Comment: If you can know which platform you are using...

`if (platform == 'windows') { $line .= '\r\n' } else { $line .= '\n' } `